# aws cli post installation issue: Errno 2 - No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I used a windows installer to install AWS CLI.

The version being used is - aws-cli/2.0.9 Python/3.7.5 Windows/7 botocore/2.0.0dev

While running command and trying to up the S3 instance using json template for coludformation getting error.

Keys are correctly configured.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

> Error parsing parameter '--template-body': Unable to load paramfile file://Desktop/EC2.json: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Desktop/EC2.json'

Comment: It seems like it just can't find the file. If you are running it on Windows - try to change '/' to '\', specify the full path starting with C:\ or just put the template in S3 and use --template-url instead.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show us the command you ran? Also, what directory were you in when running the command?